# Return all rows matching a certain id in a single result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weather database with three tables: Locations, WeekDays and Weather and they have the following columns

```
Locations
location_id | location_name

Weekdays
day_id | day_name

Weather
location_id | day_id | max_temp | min_temp | avg_temp | humidity | rainfall | windspeed
```

`location_id` and `day_id` are foreign keys. Now I need to return all weather elements of a certain location  for the whole week Sunday - Monday in a single result. I am sure I'm supposed to use keywords like `AS 'monday_max_temp'`, `AS 'tuesday_rainfall'` etc. The results should be 7(days)* the number of weather elements i have in the database for each location. Can someone help me with the kind of sql query I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just store the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters:

```
SELECT
Locations.location_id, Locations.location_name,
Weekdays.day_id, Weekdays.day_name,
Weather.*
FROM Locations
CROSS JOIN Weekdays
LEFT JOIN Weather
ON Weekdays.day_id = Weather.day_id AND Locations.location_id = Weather.location_id
```

Can you explain a little more about the 'keywords'. What do you mean/want with them?

Why do you want to exclude the location? You don't want seven days for each location?

I've seen your reply and I will show you the SQL. You can do what you ask in the SLQ, but there will be not much programmers that will choose this approach. It is usily better to make the crosstab in the presentation.

```
SELECT
    Locations.location_id, Locations.location_name,
    WeatherMonday.max_temp AS monday_max_temp, WeatherMonday.min_temp AS monday_min_temp, ... ,
    WeatherTuesday .max_temp AS tues_max_temp, ... ,
    ... ,
FROM Locations
INNER JOIN Weather AS WeatherMonday ON WeatherMonday.day_id = 1 AND Locations.location_id = WeatherMonday.location_id
INNER JOIN Weather AS WeatherTuesday ON WeatherTuesday.day_id = 2 AND Locations.location_id = WeatherTuesday.location_id
...
```

Comment: Never mind about the keywords what i want is to return all the weather elements for each location from monday to sunday. Lets for example i have Location called Paris, I want to return all the weather elements of Paris from monday to sunday in one result e.g location: paris, monday_max_temp: 10, monday_min_temp:06, monday_avg_temp:04, tuesday_max_temp: 20. For all the days for any given location

Comment: I have tried what you gave me and its almost close to what i am looking for. The only difference is that yours returns the weather elements for each day for a location in seperate rows whereas i want all the weather elements for all the days for a certain location in one row. I hope you understand

Comment: Thanks man i almost got it to work but i ran into one small problem. That all the locations are returning the weather elements of the first location. If i can only get that one to work i will be  good to go

Comment: I forgot about that. I've added this to the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM Weather WHERE location_id = "desired id" order by day_id desc limit 7;
```

Asuming your day_id is auto increment field and you add a row for each day. You will get last 7 rows for desired location orderd from last insert to first.